# basic query on associative arrays

Tags: php, mysql

How to do I query this in?

Graph is working on this query

```
$dataPoints = array();

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM service_booking GROUP BY service_id");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{        
    $point = array("label" => $row['service_id'] , "y" => $row['booking_id']);

    array_push($dataPoints, $point);        
}
```

but I want the "label" `$row['service_id']` display as a `['services']` coming from a different parent table.

```
  services (tbl1)                            service_booking (tbl2) 
 services || service_id                     service_id ||  booking id
```

Comment: you mean joining the tables and using the `services` column values? just use a `JOIN` statement in your query like you normally would do

Comment: Do you want the service_id to display as services or do you want the services column to display?

Comment: @jerome thanks in advance. currently service_id being displayed is an integer. I want the graph to display the name of the services. which is @ a different table. I'll try your proposed query below. appreciate it.!

Comment: it works now, thanks a lot. Ghost & Jerome.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables

```
SELECT b.*, s.services
FROM service_booking AS b
JOIN services AS s ON s.service_id = b.service_id
```